# Change "tiapp.xml" depending on deploy type using Titanium/ Appcelerator/ Alloy

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am using Appcelerator Alloy (same issue probably applies to Titanium).

I have the following in my `tiapp.xml`:

```
...
<plist>
    <dict>
        ...
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <value>blah</value>
        ...
    </dict>
</pict>
...
```

The issue I have is that I have 2 FacebookAppID's. I have one for testing and another for production.

How can I set it so that it changes depending on the deploy type.

I know this is possible in the `config.json`, as you just put it under `env:development`, `env:test` or `env:production`. But how do you do it `tiapp.xml` in

Answer (score 2):

There is no build in method to change tiapp on the fly. However there is a nice open source solution to switch.

https://github.com/jasonkneen/TiTh

Another option is to use [grunt-titanium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-titanium).